# Is there a difference in meaning between "aggregate" and "aggregated"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

The word is meant to be used as a description of the summarized number/count of something (e.g. aggregate(d) consumption of heating oil, consumed by all households in a country).
I've seen both words and now I am wondering whether they have the same meaning and whether one of them should be preferred.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Aggregated" is the past tense construction of the verb "to aggregate".  In contrast, "aggregate" is an adjective ("aggregated is not an adjective).

> The company **aggregated** sales figures to check expectations. *(verb)*
>   The **aggregate** sales of the company exceeded expectations. *(adjective)*

For your phrase:

> The **aggregate consumption** of oil consumed to heat households in the country is more than three times the next largest national consumption.

(To be fair, the use of the past tense verb as an adjective is not strictly wrong.  In English, we can take nearly any verb and apply it as an adjective: "an exploded bomb", "a convinced electorate", "the totaled figures".  However, because there is a specifically defined adjective for this particular word, I would suggest sticking with the completely correct "aggregate".)

Comment: Of course, "aggregate" is also something you put in concrete.

Comment: Yes, there are mineral-related definitions to "aggregate", both as noun and adjective, though I suspect that won't be too useful for the OP's concerns.

Comment: It's notable that the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) use "*aggregated*" as an adjective the way you described